# How to prove that there are not more than five different Galois groups of irreducible separable polynomial of degree 4

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let $F$ be a field and $f\in F[x]$ a polynomial that is irreducible, separable and of degree $4$.

> How do I prove that there are not more than $5$ different possibilities for the Galois group Gal($f$) (not counting isomorphisms)?

I found multiple answers/sites that determine exactly what the Galois groups can be. But those were a little too advanced for me, since I just got  introduced to Galois theory. I think that's also the reason why the question says 'not more than 5' instead of being more specific.
So maybe somebody can help?

Edit: @DietrichBurde has helped a lot here below by giving a source that says that Gal($f$) must be a transitive subgroup of $S_4$, of which there are only five. However, it's not clear for me why it must be a transitive subgroup of $S_4$.

Answer (score 1):

A very detailed and elementary reference are the notes of Keith Conrad on [Galois groups of cubics and quartics](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjk4vubxO3LAhXkO5oKHWQdC_QQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.uconn.edu%2F~kconrad%2Fblurbs%2Fgaloistheory%2Fcubicquartic.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGI4_d1S21mFaiShArghp8yQFIwdg&sig2=nQKlt9W0B9dCK8Gd4C5agg&bvm=bv.118443451,d.bGQ). In Section $3$ it is proved that we have exactly $5$ possibilities, for $Gal(f)$, namely the groups $S_4,A_4,D_4,C_4$ and $C_2\times C_2$, which are just the transitive subgroups of $S_4$. In Theorem $1.1$ it is proven that $f$ is irreducible if and only if $Gal(f)$ is a transitive subgroup of $S_4$. However, it is easy to see that there are at most $5$ transitive subgroups of $S_4$, see Section $3$.

Comment: The last sentence of this answer is probably what the OP needs since that's what implies the "not more than 5".

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what discs and squares are in your source. Also where is it proven that Gal(f) must be a transitive subgroup of $S_4$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I think OP might be referring to the fact that Theorem $1.1$ is not, in fact, proved in the notes.

Answer (score 0):

It is not difficult to prove that if $f$ is irreducible over $F$, then $G=Gal(f)$ must act transitively on the roots of $f$. Briefly, suppose $\alpha$ is a root of $f$ in a splitting field $K$, and $\underline{\alpha}=G\cdot\alpha$ is the orbit of $\alpha$. Then $G$ fixes any symmetric polynomial in $\underline{\alpha}$ which shows that $e_\lambda(\underline{\alpha})\in F$ for every elementary symmetric function (since this is precisely the fixed point space for the action of $G$).

But, then $g(x)=\prod_{\beta\in G\cdot\alpha}(x-\beta)\in F[x]$ because when we multiply out the product, the coefficients are elementary symmetric functions in the elements of $G\cdot\alpha$.

Now, $g(x)$ is non-constant (because $g(\alpha)=0$) and $g(x)|f(x)$ (because all the roots of $g(x)$ in $K$ are roots of $f(x)$ in $K$). Hence, $g(x)=a f(x)$ for some nonzero $a\in F$. It now follows that $G\cdot\alpha$ must contain every root of $f$.